# Need help writing to a SQL Server CE table

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have been trying to get the below code to write to my SQL Server CE database for months without success. My try catches do not catch an errors thrown but my data is not written. Does anyone see anything wrong with the way I am doing this?

```
conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = LaZSolutions.sdf");
conn.Open();

var id = Guid.NewGuid();

SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Mobile, Email, CustomerNum) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @HomePhone, @MobilePhone, @Email, @CustomerNum)";

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhone", txtHPhone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhone", txtMPhone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtState.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNum", id);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn1 = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = LaZSolutions.sdf");
conn1.Open();

SqlCeCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderNum, OrderDate, Cost, [Open], Comments) VALUES(@OrderNum, @OrderDate, @Cost, @Open, @Comments)";

cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.Connection = conn1;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNum", txtOrderNum.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", txtOrderdate.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", lblPrice.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Open", open);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNum", id);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", txtComments.Text);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn1.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: you don't need to open the connection twice

Comment: Do you have your SDF file listed in the project items?  Do you check the contents of this file using Server Manager window? Where is located the database file shown by the Server Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct (though you are not enclosing your disposable elements with the using statement and open without need two times the same connection) but, your SDF file is listed in the connection string without any path. This means that this file should be in the same folder where your program runs. When you debug your program the executable runs in the BIN\DEBUG directory and, if your insert succeds, the data is inserted in the SDF file present in the BIN\DEBUG directory.

You could check if your inserts work assigning an integer variable to the return value of ExecuteScalar. If this variable is 1 then your code has inserted the record.

Now, if you check the contents of the file using `Server Manager` you need to be sure that the database shown is the same database in the BIN\DEBUG and not the base file usually present in the root of your project folder.

Another possibility is a problem with the write permissions on the folder where the file is located, but this should result in an exception.